# Is that possible to pay someone using their registered Email ID on STRIPE

Tags: stripe-payments

i m building a online selling store like ebay and I want to pay sellers by using their registered STRIPE email ID (foobar@example.com) (like paypal do so) without connecting him/her in my stripe platform .

> Remember I want pay seller using his stripe Email Id not stripe account Id which looks like acct_123dsfg****

if you know how to do that please let me Know :) Thanks

Comment: You could store a table in your database that linked emails to account ids, but you must use connect and the account id would be required via the api

Answer (score 0):

Using stripe gateway you can pay your seller's by following 2 methods only:

1) Seller can configure their stripe account from store dashboard (by adding their publishable key and secret key) and site admin transfer the appropriate amount into seller account.

2) Using stripe connect ( https://stripe.com/docs/connect ).

I think currently stripe do not provide any such functionality that you can pay your seller's using their stripe email id only.

Comment: The site admin cannot transfer funds using just the publishable key and secret key. With that they could create charges on your account though. Sharing keys is also not recommended for security purposes as you can't revoke those keys without revoking your main api key.